# How to read/access Power Bi Embedded Report query string parameters from on-premise SSAS?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We are trying to find a way for SSAS to access query string parameters. I know about the filter-parameter, which is greatly documented, but we need to pass a custom parameter - a sessioncookie - so instead of

- ?filter=Store/Territory eq 'NC'

we need to pass

- ?sess=

This is needed in order to implement a 2-factor authentication mechanism, so someone stealing the credentials necessary for getting an embed token, cannot compromise the setup by using those credentials from anywhere in the world.

The idea is as follows:

We have an on-premise website (angular + API) - right now based on AppOwnsData sample. When the user requests a report, the embedtoken is retrieved from PowerBI.com, and then a sessioncookie with a short lifetime is generated and stored in a local MSSQL database. This sessioncookie is then appended to the report url as a parameter.

The user is now redirected to powerbi.com to fetch the report. powerbi.com (utilizing an embedded capacity) will connect to the on-premise SSAS through an on-premise gateway. SSAS accesses the "sess" query string parameter and verifies that the session cookie content matches a session cookie stored in the MSSQL table and that the lifetime for that cookie has not expired.

We cannot find any documentation on how to do this. We have tried passing it as a part of the EffectiveIdentity and attempted using CustomData, but haven't been successful yet.

Can anyone point us in the right direction of how to solve it?

Obviously it would be awesome if Microsoft solved this single-point-or-compromisation by adding IP-filtering to powerbi.com, or implemented a true 2 factor b2b-solution, but I am not sure we can wait for that to happen :)

Comment: I might be missing something here, but the security in PowerBI is based on Azure AD. Unless you're using some hard coded master account in the embedding, you should be able to handle this in azure?. In Azure AD, you are able to make sure, the credentials aren't been used from everywhere in the world and also enable multi-factor-authentication. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by SSAS reading the query string parameter, it's not made for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the your sessioncookie using CustomData. This article has a good explanation of how you can implement CustomData http://www.businessintelligenceinfo.com/business-intelligence/self-service-bi/using-customdata-and-ssas-with-power-bi-embedded

```
// Generate Embed Token for reports without effective identities.
var rls = new EffectiveIdentity("xxxAzureUserName", new List<string> { report.DatasetId }, new List<string>() { "SessionCookie" }, "CookieValue");

generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view", identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { rls });`
```